# Multiple modals vs one overwritable modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to set up a page which will have multiple elements in it. Could be something like books galery where when you click on the thumbnail a modal opens up with the picture of the book, link to publisher (or personal book page) and a description.

I was wondering whether it's more prudent to generate 1 modal per thumbnail (no js needed to manage anything and quick setup) or to setup one modal in which that data would be overwritten depending on which thumbnail you're clicking (less html generated but more complex to set up requiring js and storing information somewhere like `data` attribute).

I've seen a lot of topics and coverage regarding modals but haven't seen question like that asked so far. Everyone seems to be spamming countless modal "elements" without question.

Could someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the question for it to be getting downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

The more efficient and future proof approach would be to incorporate JavaScript. As you would only be storing the data for each book and a single template modal this would conserve bandwidth. Additionally, what if you wanted to add more books? Just adding the data to the "books" array would be much easier in the future rather than having to create a new modal for each new entry.

However, if the gallery size is very small it may not be worth the time and effort to do this.

Hence, this is a design choice, it's up to you to decide what would be the ideal approach for your project.

Comment: Those were exactly my thoughts, though since the galery elements would be generated through a loop (new modal with a different data would/could be generated the same way and thus adding new elements would not pose a problem. It just seemed like whole lot of content for barely any reason (as far as I can see at the moment)